# Powershell sort a text file after a specific char

Tags: powershell, sorting

Im actually trying to sort a .txt file with a powershell script after a specific char ( " ____ " ) and after that those four underscore I need to sort, any tips or link that could help me ?

The file can look like this :

```
blablabla_12345____nameToSort
blablaree_53624____nameToSort
```

Actually the code look just like this :

```
Get-Content Desktop/test.txt | sort | get-unique > Desktop/result.txt
```

And so, it sort the text file by the first char and not  the actual name
Thanks for your help

Comment: The file look like this :

blablabla_12345____nameToSort

And so I need to sort only on the name, and nop the beginning of the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort on a calculated piece of the text like:

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\bla.txt' | 
Sort-Object {($_ -split '_{4}')[-1]} -Unique | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Test\result.txt'
```

Comment: That seem's to work, the '_{4}' actually mean the four underscore ?

Comment: @ytbjr Yes, `'_{4}'` is regex and indeed means to split on exactly 4 underscores.

Comment: Thanks for your fast raply, that help me a lot !